# Give an example of a compact metric space $X$ such that $X$ and $X\times X$ are homeomorphic

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

Give an example of a  compact metric space $X$ such that $X$ and $X\times X$ are homeomorphic.($|X|>1)$

Please suggest me ways on how should I think about this.Its quite sure that $X$ cant be finite.

I tried discrete topology where the conditions got well except its compact.

Comment: Instead of using the discrete topology, try using the trivial topology. (i.e. the only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$.) I think that this gives $X×X$ the trivial topology as well, but you should check that as I didn't.

Comment: @RolfSievers This is not metric as soon as $\vert X\vert >1$.

Comment: Thank you, I missed the "metric" constraint.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: look at infinite powers $X^I$ of finite discrete spaces $X$, e.g. $X=\{0,1\}$. This provides non-trivial Hausdorff examples. To get a metric example you need to take a little bit of care on (the cardinality of) the index set.

Edit: $X$ need not be finite but can be any compact metric space.

Answer (score 3):

$X=\{0\}$ works, doesn't it? Both $X$ and $X\times X$ have only one element.

Answer (score 1):

Any one-point space (which is finite, yes) *clearly* verifies this... And now, you're going to edit your question and say : "please help to find a compact $X$ that is not one point, such that $X$ and $X\times X$ are homeomorphic"...